# post cross domain without access to the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, easyxdm

is there a way to send a AJAX post to a PHP page that is in a server that I don't have access? The server always send Access Control Allow Origin error, because I'm sending a post from my server (that I have access) to another server (that I don't' have access). It seems that this server that I don't own only accepts post from it.

Any code, tip? I found easyxdm to do that but I don't' know how to use it.

Comment: I had similar issue.. (or I think it is).. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12683349/297641 answer to get some idea.

Comment: in case the script is accessible from web f.e. from a browser it should work also

Answer (score 0):

Yes, send the post using your php server(not javascript). That's your only option if you don't have access to the other server and they aren't returning proper CORS headers.