# Cross-domain request with ajax without json-data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, jsonp

I want to make a cross-domain request with ajax to get non-JSON(!) data (CSV-File). I'm using following code:

```
$.ajax({
      "url": dataset.url,
      "dataType": "text",
      "crossDomain": true
    }).done(function(data) {

      });
```

But it is not working because of the cross-domain restriction. When i set the datatype to "jsonp", it's also not working because the data will be interpreted and i get syntax errors.

Are there any workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issue sometime back.. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611469/get-list-of-jquery-ui-themes-from-an-url-same-origin-policy

Comment: Enable [CORS](http://enable-cors.org) on the server with your dataset.

Comment: You can either wrap the csv data into a jsonp response on the other domain's server or make your get to a script on your server that simply get and return the csv data (kind of proxy).

Comment: You can use CORS, but keep in mind that support for it is lacking with IE. IE7 doesn't support it at all, and IE8-10 you'll have to handle the request yourself (no `$.ajax` unless you extend it) because IE uses a different xhr object for CORS requests. Best would be to just make the request from your server.

Comment: Thank you guys! I don't want to use YQL and CORS so i need to write a proxy-script right?

Comment: Right, that would be the only other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following options:

1. Use **server side proxy**
2. **JSONP**, wrap csv into jsonp response
3. Use **CORS** (check cross browser support)