# source of json in Multiselect jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, multi-select

I have a multiselect of jQuery and I want to get the source from json.
I took the source code from my autocomplete combobox that works, but here it does not work.

My code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var warning = $("#message");
        $("select").multiselect({
            //selectedText: function (numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems) {
            //    return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
            //},
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON('http://' + $("[id$='ip']").val() + "/JSON/Auctocomplete.aspx?city=1&term=" + request.term, function (data) { response(data); });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#mfr").textContent = ui.item.id;
            },
            selectedList: 5,
            header: "choose up to 5",
            click: function (e) {
                if ($(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 5) {
                    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("choose up to 5");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved using YQL - Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12941673/297641 and see if this is any helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched, and I think there is not a **source** property for Jquery multiselect. Take a look at http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget . Are you sure there is a source property for it?

I advice you, first load select from json, then convert it to multiselect.

```
// The empty select element:
<select></select>

// In javascript:
$(document).ready(function () {
     var url = 'http://...';

     $.getJSON(url,function(result){
               $.each(result, function(i, field){
                      var option = $('<option value="' + field.value + '">' + field.text + '</option>');
                      $('select').append(option);
               });

               $('select').multiselect({...});
     });
});
```

Comment: How can I convert from select to multiselect? and how can I get json into the select?

Comment: $("select").multiselect({ ... as you did, turns select to multiselect. Before this, you should fill select elements with json data with javascript.

Answer (score 7):

this is because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.

[for more information please refer this link](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html)