# Not receiving response from php JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to receive a response from a php which gives back a response in the following format:

PHP response

```
 response=1
```

JQUERY

```
$.get('getstate.php', {
    email: $('#game-email').val(),
    country: 'DE',
    lang: lang,
    source: 'promotion'
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I load the php in a browser it gives me the correct response in the browser:

getstate.php?email=test@gmail.com&country=DE

but when I try to receive a response and show the value received in the variable data nothing appears. What could I be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use jquery utility functions like `$.get` or `$.ajax` with type as `GET`.

If you are able to get result in browser url, then the result is coming for a `GET` request and here in `jquery` code you are making a post request.

**UPDATED TO COMMENTS**

> "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

This issue comes when you are probably making a ajax request to a page in another domain or when you load the page directly via double clicking on it without going through the host url.

ie instead of `file:///` in url address you should have same domain name on which the php page you are requesting.

### IF YOU ARE MAKING A CROSS DOMAIN AJAX REQUEST

If your ajax request target page lies in another domain, you can do a Cross domain ajax request

you should set

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

header on your server which hosts the ajax target page. Setting the value to `*` means it will allow requests from any domain, so it makes security venerable as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity).

also at the client end you may use Jquery.ajax utility function with the `crossDomain` setting set to true.  Also this will have issues that it wont work in IE versions.

see some [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls) describing this issue.

[this article](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie) on jquery docs, discusses the same issue and has a suggestion mentioned via including a js fix file which i have tried myself before and got working.

Below are some related links for setting the CORS support in various servers and doing the ajax call at client side.

[add CORS support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

[use CORS from JavaScript](http://enable-cors.org/client.html)

Comment: @user1937021 : did you check in chrome inspector or firebug console for any errors?

Comment: in chrome it gives me an error yes, it says "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: thanks, but problem is the php is on another domain to my html. Can I still make the connection?