# AJAX request not working in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser, cross-domain

This AJAX code is working in IE10+ and Chrome and another browser, but it is not working in IE8 and IE9.

```
<table id="table" border="1"> 
    <tbody style="display: table-row-group"></tbody>
</table>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.support.cors = true;

    var url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%22%2C%20%22CADUSD%22%2C%20%22GBPUSD%22%2C%20%22AEDUSD%22%2C%20%22TRYUSD%22%2C%20%22RUBUSD%22%2C%20%22INRUSD%22%2C%20%22SARUSD%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";

    var $tbody = $('#table').find('tbody');
    var $thead = $('#table').find('thead');

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("lev 2 ");
        var ObjectKeys = Object.keys(data.query.results.rate[0]);
        var row = "<tr>";
        row += "</tr>";
        $thead.append(row);

        $.each(data.query.results.rate, function (i, el) {
            console.log("lev 3 = " + i);
            $tbody.append($('<tr />').append($('<td />').text(el.id)).append($('<td />').text(el.Name)).append($('<td />').text(el.Rate)).append($('<td />').text(el.Ask)).append($('<td />').text(el.Bid)));
        });
    });        
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

[**DEMO Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtx2q96/1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298808/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-not-working-in-ie9 Please check this post.

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? Error message in console? Request timing out? Nothing happends? Request returns error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is IE8 doesn't support the [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) XHR, so you can't do a cross domain ajax call with the native XHR or jQuery's $.ajax.

For IE8, Microsoft decided to come up with their own cross domain XHR instead of using the CORS XHR, which is called [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you'll have to implement that to support IE8 users. An example usage can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls#11267937).

Alternatively, you could proxy the cross domain request through your local server side, making the external request a server to server situation, which won't be subject to [Same Origin Policy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)