# Cross domain request with xmlHttpRequest and Paypal

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, paypal, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to do a cross domain request with XMLHttpRequest object, because with `$.ajax` it doesn't work in IE, only in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Below is a code sample

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    CallWithXhr();
});

function CallWithXhr() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    xhr.send(); 
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var responseText = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(responseText);     
    };    
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        console.log('There was an error!');
    };
}
```

I need this call because I want to add a product to the Paypal Shopping Cart without redirecting to the Paypal Shopping Cart. I have made this thing with `$.ajax` but it didn't work in Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

The errors I get in IE are:

```
SEC7126: Redirects are not allowed for CORS preflight requests.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

In Chrome I get only one error for this script:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. The request was
>   redirected to 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home', which is
>   disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Any ideas about this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)

Comment: Use $.ajax and use XDR for older IEs assuming paypal's sandbox does CORS

Comment: $.ajax is not working in IE10 an 11 and that's why I have tried with XHR

Comment: Where is your XDR? I do not see new XDomainRequest(); anywhere