# $_POST gives error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I make an ajax call for checking the availability of the username or for the validation of the passwords etc..

the ajax part :

```
$('#usernameinput').on('keyup change', function() {
   $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"formchk.php",
       data: $("#registform").serialize(),
       dataType:"html",
       success: function(result){
         $('#span').html(result) 
         }} )});
```

php part :

```
include("connect.php");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$stm = $bgln->query("SELECT * FROM membrs where username='$username'");
    $row_cntusername = $stm->num_rows;
    if( strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])) > 20) {
        echo "<a id=\"error\">something something </a>";
            $stm->close();
        }
    elseif($row_cntusername > 0){
            echo "<a id=\"error\">In use</a>";
            $stm->close(); }
//and other checkings goes on...
```

I searched a lot but can't figure out, what is the problem here. This works fine in chrome and FF but not in IE.

Note:

- jquery library is jquery-2.1.0.min.js.
- IE version is 11.

**Edit:**
I tried to use `$_GET` instead of using `$_POST` . It worked! But this is not the solution, I am using these codes for inserting and updating data, too. And I believe it'll be better if i use $_POST when inserting and/or updating data to database.

**Edit2**

I added this in php part ;

```
if (count($_POST) == 0) {
    die('No posted data received');
}
```

I get the result of the call as 'No posted data recieved'

And I tried in javascript part;

```
document.write($("#registform").serialize())
```

It gives the value that wrote in input. So, the problem is ajax can't posts the data to the php file but gets a result from php as 'No posted data'.

I also added

```
cache: false,
```

if its a cache problem of the IE, but it didn't work, too.

Comment: Which version of IE? jQuery 2.x doesn't support IE <= 8.

Comment: You never check if the values are set with `isset()` or `!empty()`

Comment: @EdCottrell: jQuery 2.x only works with IE 9+.

Comment: !(x <= 8) == 9 <= x. Just saying. Otherwise good question with Internet Explorer guys.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Right; that's exactly what I said. I suppose I could have said `<= 8.x` or `< 9`, but I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: @EdCottrell: No, you're right.  I mis-read the `<= 8`.  I need more coffee >.>

Comment: @RocketHazmat Don't we all. :)

Comment: sorry I forgot, IE version is 11.

Comment: `console.log($("#registform").serialize());` Does it look right?

Comment: @epascarello I changed it with your suggestion but still doesn't work :(

Comment: That had nothing to do with fixing the code, it was to "DEBUG" it! See what is being sent to the server.

Comment: Use either @epascarello's code, or `document.write($("#registform").serialize())` and post the result to your question.

Comment: @NobleUplift Used both of these codes in seccess: function(result) { } and first one does nothing but yours give me a blank screen. By the way I don't know the proper way to debug, What should i do for debugging this code?

Comment: Does the `$_POST` work in Firefox? You can use Firebug. Otherwise IE development tools are built-in, and I have no idea how good they are.

Comment: Yes works great in firefox. I'll use firebug and write here again @NobleUplift

Comment: @NobleUplift I used firebug and found nothing. I used also IE's debug and it didn't find anything, too. I'll go crazy. Everything works fine in chrome and firefox. But where is the problem, this is so funny :D

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219590/strange-ajax-bug-with-ie-11

Comment: @Neo I tried "Adding a unique timestamp to URL" and "Setting the cache property". After these changes it still doesn't work on IE :( Thank you.

Comment: Well if it works well with `$_GET`, but you doesn't with `$_POST`, you can use `$_REQUEST` instead. Try this.

Comment: @djay `$_REQUEST` worked well, but I dont know if it is a proper way to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` ?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains data from both `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I believe it'll better to use $_POST for inserting or updating data. There must be a solution for these problem in my question about POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more validation on your POST data:

```
include("connect.php");

if (count($_POST) == 0) {
    die('No posted data received');
}

$fields = array('username', 'kadi', ...);
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (!isset($_POST($field)) {
        die('Missing required parameter: ' . $field);
    }
}

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$stm = $bgln->query("SELECT * FROM membrs where username='$username'");
    $row_cntusername = $stm->num_rows;
    if( strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kadi'])) > 20) {
        echo "<a id=\"error\">something something </a>";
            $stm->close();
        }
    elseif($row_cntusername > 0){
            echo "<a id=\"error\">In use</a>";
            $stm->close(); }
//and other checkings goes on...
```

Change your jQuery to use a simple object instead of a serialized string. Set a variable beforehand for each input field:

```
$('#usernameinput').on('keyup change', function() {
   var name = $('#name').val();
   // ...
   $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"formchk.php",
       data: { name : name },
       dataType:"html",
       success: function(result){
         $('#span').html(result) 
       }}
)});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. now it gives "No posted data recieved" error as you write in code. But I dont understand, why it doesn't posts the data. :(

Comment: I added an example to try with your jQuery.

Comment: I tried your example. Still works in other browsers but not in IE.

Comment: I tried to use $_GET instead of using $_POST . It worked! But this is not the solution, I am using these codes for inserting and updating data, too. And I believe it'll be better if i use $_POST when inserting and/or updating data to database.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use `POST` for calls that might not be idempotent. Try using [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of `jQuery.ajax()`.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't help :(

Comment: Did you try sending in the data as a JavaScript object instead of a string? Try reducing the form to only **one** field and then send it in. Add fields back in if you start getting data.

Comment: Serialize must have been creating a bad query string, or no string at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem, empty $_POST array, and found another solution after re-reading the jQuery docs.  If I change the ajax param: "type: 'post'" to "method: 'post'" it all works in IE as well as the other browsers...  in the PHP code the $_POST array is correctly populated.

```
$.ajax(
  {
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
```