# Ajax will not load and show data on IE 11 cause cache

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, internet-explorer, varnish

I use Ajax to check data and show it on the page, and I use varnish cache.
The data is displayed on all browsers, except on IE 11, until I deactivate the varnish cache.

```
function checkMyData() {
var surl = 'index.php?eID=thismydata';
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
    surl += '&hash=' + Math.random();
}
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: siteurl + surl,
    asynchronous: true,
    data: 'mode=datalist' +
            '&initdatalist=' + initdatalist +
            '&datastr=' + datastr,      
    success: function (answer) {
        var response;
        try {
            response = eval('(' + answer + ')');
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Err: ' + answer);
            return;
        }
        if (initdatalist == 1)
            initdatalist = 0;
        $basic_cont = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><p class="data-title">' + 
                response.firstmatch + response.otherdata + '</p></div></div>' +
                response.matches;

        $("#thisdaydata").empty();
        $($basic_cont).appendTo("#thisdaydata");
    }
});
}
```

**HTML Output for all browsers (except IE 11) :**

```
<div id="thisdaydata">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <p class="data-title">data here</span></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**HTML Output for IE 11 :**

```
<div id="thisdaydata"></div>
```

is this ajax not compatible with IE 11 ?

Answer (score 0):

IE will automatically cache responses from GET requests while other browsers will let you decide if you’d like to cache the result or not. Once IE has successfully made a GET request, it will no longer even make that AJAX call until the cache expires on that object. You can add `cache : false` value in your ajax. For more details and methods you can refer to [this article](https://www.itworld.com/article/2693447/ajax-requests-not-executing-or-updating-in-internet-explorer-solution.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219590/strange-ajax-bug-with-ie-11).

Comment: Thanks, but `cache : false` do not solve the problem

Comment: I reproduce your code on my side and I think the ajax can run well in IE11. Is there any error message showing in F12 developer tools in IE11?