# Internet Explorer and jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I wonder if somebody can help please. The code belows allows me to use the google api to retrieve address details using UK potscodes.

Everything works fine in Firefox but does absolutely nothing in Internet Explorer. Any pointers will be gratefully received.

Thanks

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function(){

(function($) {
$.fn.searchPc = function(options) {
var settings = $.extend({
address1: 'address1',
address2: 'address2',
address3: 'address3',
address4: 'address4'
}, options);

return this.each(function() {
var $el = $(this);
var $form = $el.closest('form');

$form.on('click', '.HiddenBtn', function() {

$.post('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+$el.val()+'&sensor=false', function(r) {
var lat = r['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
var lng = r['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
$.post('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&sensor=false', function(address) {
$('input[name='+settings.address2+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name']);
$('input[name='+settings.address3+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name']);
$('input[name='+settings.address4+']').val(address['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['long_name']);
});
});
});
});
};
})

(jQuery);
$('input[name=postcode]').searchPc({
address2: 'custom_field'
});

}); 
</script>

<form id="form" name="form">
<input name="postcode" id="postcode" /> 
<input name="HiddenBtn" type="button" class="HiddenBtn" value="Find address" id="HiddenBtn" /><br /><br />
<input name="address1" id="address1"/><br />
<input name="custom_field" id="custom_field" /><br />
<input name="address3"  id="address3" /><br />
<input name="address4"  id="address4" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors or warnings?

Comment: Did you try compatibility view in IE?

Comment: Here is a list of common IE problems for the google maps API http://www.easypagez.com/maps/ieworking.html

Comment: from this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error) adding this should work: jQuery.support.cors = true; It seems to be cross domain problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain internet explorer is your issue, see [Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)