# AJAX call working in Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Trying to get json data from a url which generates the bottom 3 numbers of a webpage. My ajax call works in Google chrome but not in internet explorer. After doing research I was told I needed to disable caching with `cache: false` which has not solved the problem.

Here is the sourcecode on jsfiddle with a successful ajax call. However my code will does not work on internet explorer.

http://jsfiddle.net/c2VeD/148/

```
var url = 'http://crudwebappmavenized.ncsu.cloudbees.net/stats'

$.ajax(url, {

type: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
cache: false,
success: function (result)
```

Comment: WHICH IE version is it failing in?

Comment: What version of IE, did you enable CORS etc.

Comment: Internet Explorer version 11

Answer (score 1):

IE7 and earlier doesn't support crossdomain, in IE8 or later you need to check this page "Security: Cross-Domain and Zone Policy" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28VS.85%29.aspx

EDIT

Check this answer:

[Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)