# Load gzipped txt file using ajax is not working in older IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, gzip

I'm loading gzipped txt file after page load through ajax,

### Here is my code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $.ajax({
        url : "http://example.com/something.txt.gz",
        dataType : 'html',
        cache: true,
        success : function(data)
        {  
          data=$.parseJSON(data);
          something=data;
        }
      });
});
```

**And Based on chrome**,

### Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:604800
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:95595
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Wed, 21 May 2014 11:32:02 GMT
ETag:"cf999971e6ffcaf92dc5b79a8ffe2570k90bo"
Expires:Wed, 21 May 2014 23:40:18 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 21 May 2014 03:40:19 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:FGvjLrghp01FsNxaCI348RsP1BA+b98yjYzkkzpgeJNcz9HIn36CSfWIynkl18tfqNZp
x-amz-request-id:75FD682D733FDA0Ef3D
```

Now my problem is,
This is working fine in chrome, FF, Safari and also IE9+.

But in IE8 and less than that the gzipped ajax is not working, **if I send the same file using PHP then it works** only by ajax it's not working and **unzipped version of ajax call is also working**.

Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. It was not with the gzipped content, it was a cross domain issue, **IE has no issue with gzipped content**.

IE 8 and less than that does't support **cross domain ajax** request even if I use sub-domain structure (**like amazon s3**).
Here is my problem solution [solution for my problem which I faced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)