# JQuery Ajax Error on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm making an Ajax Request, it's working in all browser, but in Internet Explorer It's not working. I need that works for internet explorer 9 +

That's the request:

```
function loadYoutubeVideos(youtubeUrl){
var url = 'youtubeUrl';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        objYoutubeVideos = responseData;
        //more functions, blablabla

    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        //error functions
    }   
});
}
```

I'm making the some code for load a Facebook Page Content. What do I do?

Comment: What's the error? *What* does not work?

Comment: IE does not like cross-domain ajax requests... You should perform an ajax call to your server and send the api request from the server and pipe the results back to the client. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to using `jsonp` format?

The `json` format has a issue when use over cross-domain (different domain).

So, you need to use `jsonp` instead of `json`, `jsonp` using javascript callback for solve the cross-domain issue.

more: http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

---

You don't need create pipe for api request.

Youtube support `jsonp` format using `&callback=` parameter.