# IE9,IE8 with AngularJS CORS returns “Access is denied” - ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In IE8 and 9 I am getting the following JavaScript Error when I'm doing a CORS webapi call:

```
Error: Access is denied.
{
  [functions]: ,
  description: "Access is denied.",
  message: "Access is denied.",
  name: "Error",
  number: -2147024891
}
```

I set up my WebApi like described here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

So the WebApi contains:

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
  {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
          config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
      [...]
```

My test AngularJS App:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app">
  <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="testController as vm">
          {{vm.test}}
          {{vm.data}}
      </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

app.js:

```
  var app = angular.module('app');

  app.controller('testController', function ($http) {
      var vm;
      vm = this;

      vm.test = "bla non no ";
      vm.data = null;

      $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'a token'

      return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          data: null,
          url: 'http://webapi.com/api/controller/getactionmethod/',
      }, function (data) {
          console.log("bla");
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("bla a");
          vm.data;
      });


  });
```

The above code / webapi calls works with chrome and IE 10. IE10 prints:

SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://webapi.com/api/controller/getactionmethod/ required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://webapi.com/api/controller/getactionmethod/ required CORS preflight.

I'm really stuck and don't know what I can try else. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232017/ie9-jquery-ajax-with-cors-returns-access-is-denied

Comment: I'm using angularjs not jQuery.

Comment: IE8 and IE9 don't support the standard CORS XHR. See my answer to this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141650/xdomainrequest-vs-xmlhttprequest

Comment: MrCode is correct. You need to use JSONP for legacy browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS

Comment: There are definitely other solutions than doing JSONP requests to solve the CORS issues in IE8/9

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS v1.2.23 does not support CORS requests for IE8 or IE9.
But IE8/9 supports CORS limited with the XDomainRequest object. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx

I tried to modify the angularjs lib like descriped here http://samuellam.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/ie-89-cors-support-in-angular-js/

But I noticed I can't send with the XDomainRequest requests a custom header. So I ended up deploying the project on the same machine with same ips which will work for IE8 and 9, which is in fact only a workaround.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with IE8/9 (Django backend instead of ASP.NET) when doing CORS requests.

There are several ways to solve this problem. The easiest and fastest solution for me was to use the polyfill from [jpillora](http://jpillora.com/xhook/example/ie-8-9-cors-polyfill.html). With this polyfill normal CORS XMLHttpRequests will be swapped out for XDR on IE8/9.

Include [XHook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) and add following before-hook to your site:

```
xhook.before(function(request, callback) {
  //skip browsers that dont use XDR
  if(!window.XDomainRequest)
    return callback();
  //skip requests that aren't cross domain
  var url = request.url;
  var loc = window.location;
  var hostname = loc.hostname + (loc.port ? ":"+loc.port : "");
  if(!/^https?:\/\/([^\?\/]+)/.test(url) || RegExp.$1 === hostname)
    return callback();

  //if not GET, force POST
  var method = request.method;
  if(method !== 'GET') method = 'POST';
  //force same protocol
  url = url.replace(/^https?:/,loc.protocol);
  //request!
  var xdr = new window.XDomainRequest();
  xdr.timeout = request.timeout;
  //proxy events
  var proxy = function(e) {
    xdr['on'+e] = function() {
      request.xhr.dispatchEvent(e);
    };
  };
  var events = ['progress','timeout','error'];
  for(var i = 0; i < events.length; ++i )
    proxy(events[i]);
  //custom onload
  xdr.onload = function() {
    callback({
      status: 200,
      statusText: "OK",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': xdr.contentType
      },
      text: xdr.responseText
    })
  };
  xdr.open(method, url);
  xdr.send(request.body);
  return
});
```

There are several other solutions:

- https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors
- https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain
- https://michiganlabs.com/easy-cors-legacy-browsers/#.VglHEye1FBd