# Unable to set content type onto ajax request header in IE 8 during POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Jquery DataTable. And using making ajax calls (**CROSS DOMAIN Request**) like this to get the data:

```
ajax: {
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
```

This is how the **header** looks for this request in **IE 8**

```
Key Value
Request POST /api/data HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Origin  http://localhost:5000
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)
Host    localhost:5555
Content-Length  3647
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

The Jquery DataTable automatically post the content to the server. But **when the request is sent through IE 8, server is not receiving any data** in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` object. I am using below code to read the data posted by the server.

```
            var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
            var direction = formData["order[0][dir]"];
            var draw = Convert.ToInt32(formData["draw"]);
            var length = Convert.ToInt32(formData["length"]);
            var start = Convert.ToInt32(formData["start"]);
```

If I post request through chrome or FireFox, I get the data on the server. **When the request is going through IE 8 content type header is not set. I think this is the reason why data is not available on the server side.** Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `dataType` instead of `contentType`.  As per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you need to use `contentType` when setting what the browser is sending and `dataType` when specifying what the browser is expecting to receive.

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> Type: String
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). The W3C
>   XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always
>   UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change
>   the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content
>   type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a
>   preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried setting contentType as well but looks like IE 8 does not send this information. Check this link point no 4.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Is it cross domain then?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I don't think its a CORS issues. As I am able to call the correct end point of the server. we are using jquery plugin to overcome CORD issue. Only problem is the content posted through request body, is not available under `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`. Earlier we were calling the same endpoint as GET request and everything was working. Now we changed the request type to `POST`. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, On the server side, I am now reading the form data like this:

```
var formData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

earlier I was trying to read data like this: `var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;`

As mentioned in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) point 4, IE 8 does not send `contentType` in the request header. And the link also talks about manually reading the request body which is what I am doing now.