# AJAX with JSON fails to show up in Internet Explorer

Tags: ajax, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to display Wordpress blog posts on a different domain. It displays on all browsers except for IE.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'www.whatevermywordpresswebsiteis.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=100',
     crossDomain: true,
     cache: false,
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     type: 'GET',
     async: false,
     data: { action : 'get_ajax_posts' },
     success: function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(i, _post) {
         console.log(data);
     });
     }
     });
```

I've tried to implement XDomainRequest as well but it still fails to work ([Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls#11267937)). I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: You have to enable CORS on source project (www.whatevermywordpresswebsiteis.com)

Comment: @Mertez The CORS was enabled in the functions.php file.

Comment: It's been a while - but the solution was that the whole .js file wasn't running adequately on behalf of template literals